# Solving recurrence of 3 variables using generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

This comes from another question in Wilf's *generatingfunctionology* book (the part highlighted in light yellow):

[image: Question 1, Exercise 20]

If I read the question right, if I do it for $n=3$ (and assuming a substring like $111$ is considered to have 3 consecutive $1$'s and something like $01010$ has 2 non-consecutive $1$'s):
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& m & k \\ \hline
000 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
001 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
010 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
011 & 2 & 0 \\ \hline
100 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
101 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
110 & 2  & 0 \\ \hline
111 & 3 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

So this means $f(3,1,1)=3, f(3,2,0)=2$ and $f(3,3,0) = 1$ for instance.

I have then found the recurrence in the form:

$$f(n,m,k) = f(n-1,m,k) + f(n-2,m-1,k-1) + \sum_{t \geq 0} {f((n-3)-t,(m-3)+1-t,k)}$$

Where:

- The first term is the case when we have $01$ at the start of the string.
- The 2nd term when we have $10$ at start of string.
- The 3rd term is when we have $110$, $1110$, $11110$, etc at the start of the string.

With base cases:

- $f(1,0,0)=f(1,1,1)=1$, and
- $f(n,n,0) =1$ if $n = 0$ or $n > 1$.

And also some other conditions, including $n,m,k\geq 0$, $n\geq m$ and $m\geq k$

This leads me to part (b) of the question where I could multiply the recursion by $x^n y^m$ and sum it, or sum for $n$ or $m$ separately by first defining $A_{m,k} = \sum _{n\geq 0} {f(n,m,k)x^n}$, for example. However, I am confused as to how to deal with the 3rd term.

I believe I may have read the question incorrectly (since there's a mentioning of $k=1,2,...$, but I'm having trouble understanding what the question is asking for otherwise), but am still curious if this recurrence could be solved and would like to ask for hints/help as to how to approach this recurrence, or if I am reading the question right.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the generating function we get  more or less by inspection that it
is given by

$$F_k(x, y) = (1+x+x^2+\cdots)
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0} (y+y^2+\cdots+y^{k-1})^q (x+x^2+\cdots)^q
\\ \times (1+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{k-1})
\\ = (1+x+x^2+\cdots)
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0} x^q y^q (1+y+\cdots+y^{k-2})^q (1+x+\cdots)^q
\\ \times (1+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{k-1})
.$$

This is

$$F_k(x, y) = \frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-xy(1-y^{k-1})/(1-y)/(1-x)}
\frac{1-y^{k}}{1-y}
\\ = \frac{1-y^{k}}{(1-x)(1-y)-xy(1-y^{k-1})}
\\ = \frac{1-y^k}{1-x-y+xy^k}.$$

For the explicit formula we write

$$F_k(x, y) = \frac{1-y^k}{1-y-x(1-y^k)}
= \frac{1-y^k}{1-y} \frac{1}{1-x(1-y^k)/(1-y)}.$$

Extracting the coefficient on $x^n$ first followed by $y^m$ we get

$$[x^n] [y^m] F_k(x,y) = 
[y^m] \frac{1-y^k}{1-y} \frac{(1-y^k)^n}{(1-y)^n}
= [y^m] \frac{(1-y^k)^{n+1}}{(1-y)^{n+1}}
\\ = [y^m] \frac{1}{(1-y)^{n+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose q} (-1)^q y^{kq}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose q} (-1)^q
[y^{m-kq}] \frac{1}{(1-y)^{n+1}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor m/k \rfloor} {n+1\choose q} (-1)^q 
{m+n-kq\choose n}.$$

We now  present a combinatorial  recurrence. Observe that  $f(n,m,k) -
f(n,m,k-1)$ gives the  strings where a block of $k-1$  ones appears at
least once. Now there are two cases.  The first appearance is right at
the  beginning  or   at  the  end  and  we   get  $f(n-1,m+1-k,k)$  or
$f(n-1,m+1-k,k-1)$ possibilities because the run of $k-1$ ones must be
followed / preceded by a zero.   The second is that the inital segment
before the  first appearance of  such a block  has length $p\ge  0$ to
$n+m-k-1$ followed by the $k-1$ ones surrounded by zeros followed by a
string of  length $n+m-p-(k+1)$ from  the set  that has at  most $k-1$
consecutive  ones. This  yields with  $q$ the  number of  ones in  the
prefix

$$f(n,m,k) = f(n,m,k-1) + f(n-1,m+1-k, k) + f(n-1,m+1-k,k-1) \\ +
\sum_{p=0}^{n+m-k-1} 
\sum_{q=0}^m f(p-q, q, k-1) f(n-2+q-p, m+1-q-k,k).$$

There  is  some Maple  code  to  help  explore these  recurrences  and
generating functions  which also includes the  boundary conditions for
the recurrence.

```
with(combinat);

RL :=
proc(n, m, k)
    option remember;
    local res, iter;

    iter :=
    proc(restx, resty, d)
    local pos, cur, runlen;

        if restx = 0 and resty = 0 then
            cur := -1; pos := 1; runlen := 0;

            while pos <= m+n do
                if d[pos] <> cur then
                    cur := d[pos];
                    runlen := 1;
                else
                    runlen := runlen + 1;

                    if cur = 1 and runlen >= k then
                        break;
                    fi;
                fi;

                pos := pos + 1;
            od;

            if pos = n+m+1 then
                if cur = 0 or (cur = 1 and runlen < k)
                then
                    res := res + 1;
                fi;
            fi;
        fi;

        if restx > 0 then
            iter(restx-1, resty, [op(d), 0]);
        fi;
        if resty > 0 then
            iter(restx, resty-1, [op(d), 1]);
        fi;
    end;

    res := 0;
    iter(n, m, []);
    res;
end;

EX := (n, m, k) ->
coeftayl(coeftayl((1-y^k)/(1-x-y+x*y^k),
                  x=0, n), y=0, m);

EX2 := (n, m, k) ->
add(binomial(n+1,q)*(-1)^q*
    binomial(m+n-k*q, n), q=0..floor(m/k));

f :=
proc(n, m, k)
option remember;

    if n < 0 or m < 0 then return 0 fi;

    if n = 0 and m = 0 then return 1 fi;

    if n = 0 then
        if m <= k-1 then
            return 1
        else
            return 0
        fi;
    fi;

    if m = 0 then return 1 fi;

    if k <= 1 then return 0 fi;

    f(n,m,k-1) + f(n-1,m+1-k,k) + f(n-1, m+1-k, k-1) +
    add(add(f(p-q, q, k-1)*f(n-2+q-p, m+1-q-k, k),
            q=0..m), p=0..n+m-k-1);
end;
```

There   is  also   a  recurrence   that  is   algebraic  rather   than
combinatorial. We start from the observation that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F_k(x, y) = F_k^2(x, y).$$

Extracting coefficients on $[x^{n-1}] [y^m]$ yields

$$f(n, m, k) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^m
f(p, q, k) f(n-1-p, m-q, k).$$

This is implemented below.

```
g :=
proc(n, m, k)
option remember;

    if n < 0 or m < 0 then return 0 fi;

    if n = 0 and m = 0 then return 1 fi;

    if n = 0 then
        if m <= k-1 then
            return 1
        else
            return 0
        fi;
    fi;

    if m = 0 then return 1 fi;

    if k <= 1 then return 0 fi;

    1/n*add(add(g(p, q, k)*g(n-1-p, m-q, k),
                q=0..m), p=0..n-1);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I found [another answer](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~boyd/math331/Wilf.1.20.pdf) to the correct interpretation of the problem (unlike mine but like yours) which writes it as $f(n,m,k) = \sum _{q=0} ^{\lfloor m/k \rfloor} (-1)^q {n-kq\choose n-m} {n-m+1 \choose q}$. However, if I take $n:= n-m$ from your answer then it is the same. I wanted to ask if both of your answers are still equivalent then.

Comment: Oh, never mind. Your generating function treats $x$ as number of $0$'s and $y$ as total number of $1$'s, while as the other answer treats $x$ as counting both $0$'s and $1$'s.

Comment: It appears there is a much more symmetric recurrence which can be derived from the generating function. I have included this recurrence above.

Comment: I re-read the combinatorial recurrence, I think there is a misreading. For example (in the first case), wouldn't the $f(n-1,m+1-k,k)$ be also counting strings with $k-2$ or less consecutive 1's, which is also counted in $f(n-1,m+1-k,k-1)$? Would it just be enough to add a zero + $k-1$ ones on the right or left side only, and not consider both sides?

Comment: Observe that the two recurrences produce the same values as the enumeration routine. The two sets that you refer to are disjoint as the first one has the first occurrence of a $k-1$ block at the beginning (followed by a sequence where blocks of one are at most $k-1$) and the second one at the end (preceded by a sequence with those blocks at most $k-2$). As the first occurrence of the $k-1$ block is in different positions there is no overlap.